# Switching between RTL and LTR in android

Tags: android

I am making an android app that is going to be in Arabic (RTL) and English (LTR) and the user can switch between RTL and LTR from the app . Will i have to make xml files for both design differently , which does not sound like a good idea.
There are a lot of textview and radiobuttons which i don't want to align separately for both so what is the suggestion that what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

you can make it this when create xmls in arabic (/res/Layout-ar) and another xmls in XML (/res/Layout) and the same thing in drawable , values. i think this is the perfect method to create multilingual App .

you can customize textview and radio button ,..... from when write gravity = right if its arabic

example radioButton in arabic:

```
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
        android:gravity="right" />
```

Comment: Wont this be needing my users mobile locale to be switched to arabic ?

Comment: yes , we need you make the switch button between 2 languages and then save what language selected in shared preference file then we lunch app with languages selected. 

if Arabic selected:
Localization.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setLanguage("ar");

if english selected:
Localization.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setLanguage("en");

Comment: But if i want the user to be able to select the language from the app then what should i do?

Comment: when the user select the prefer language save this lang in shared preferences file code in the below , then you can make restart the app to refresh UI with the language selected , they load all files for the language selecteted.  :)